# How to change permission of a kvm-qemu serial console output log

Tags: linux, logging, qemu, kvm

I have a virtual machine with this config to redirect serial console log to another file:

```
<devices>
   ...
   <console type="pty">
       <target type="sclp"/> 
       <log file="/home/nptusk/serial-console.log" append="on"/>
   </console>
</devices>
```

For automation reasons I want the log to have the permission other than root:root. What can I do to achieve this without using chown afterwards, in other words the log file when generated already has my desired user and group.

Answer (score 0):

Kvm deamon is running on root.Otherwise it changes its uid,there is no way to change owner.But you can change its permssion to 665 or 664 so that you can access it,or change its ACL for more security